next js Request not send cookie
i have external api in express js in next js (frontend) while im storing a cookie in the browser after a successful login. However, when making subsequent requests to the server, the cookie is not being sent with the request, even though it is stored in the browser's cookie storage.
// actions.ts (next js frontend)
"use server";
export async function login(state: any, formData: FormData) {
  const cookieStore = await cookies();
  const rawFieldData = {
    email: formData.get("email"),
    password: formData.get("password"),
  };

const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(rawFieldData),
      credentials: "include",
    });

    const cookieHeader = res.headers.getSetCookie();
    cookieHeader.forEach((cookie) => {
      const [name, ...parts] = cookie.split("=");
      const value = parts.join("=").split(";")[0];

      cookieStore.set(name, value, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        sameSite: "lax",
        path: "/",
      });
    });
    return { message: "success login" };
}



// auth-controller.ts (express backend):

const login = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const request = loginValidate.safeParse(req.body as LoginUserRequest);
    const { userWithoutPassword: user, token, refreshToken } = await authService.login(request.data);

    res.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: "lax",
      path: "/",
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    });

    res.cookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: "lax",
      path: "/",
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    });

  res.status(200).json({
      status: "Success",
      code: 200,
      data: user,
      message: "Login successful",
    });
};

